# Why I get this error when saving Twitter ACAccount?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter, acaccount

I'm trying to save a Twitter account into the `ACAccountStore`.

I'm authenticating the user with `MPOauth` (this works perfectly, I can authenticate and post a message) and when I receive the access token and the access token secret I proceed to save the account.

First of all, I split the token access for taking only the token itself, not the user ID. After that this is my code

```
if ([username length] > 0 && [token length] > 0 && [secret length] > 0) {

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    ACAccount *account = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:accountType];
    ACAccountCredential *credentials = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:token tokenSecret:secret];

    [account setCredential:credentials];
    [account setUsername:username];

    [accountStore saveAccount:account withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        if (success) {

            NSLog(@"the account was saved!");

        } else {

            NSLog(@"the account was NOT saved");
        }

        [accountStore release];
        [account release];
        [credentials release];
    }];
}
```

But never works, I get this

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
```

I read that this responds to an error authenticating the data against Twitter, thing that is done by iOS5 framework before saving the account.

I've already read [this reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800675/error-migrating-existing-oauth-credentials-to-acaccountstore) and the post in [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/migrating-tokens-core-accounts).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if token is OAToken you should replace this

```
ACAccountCredential *credentials = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:token tokenSecret:token];
```

with this

```
ACAccountCredential *outhCredential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:token.key tokenSecret:token.secret];
```

You should pass key & secret as 1st and 2nd arguments respectively .

Comment: Nope, it's not a OAToken object, I pass the token and secret as NSString objects. Anyway, I will have the same problem, right?

Comment: Arrrrrrghhhhhhh, I'm stupid T_T I'm passing `token` and `token` as params, not `token` and `secret`. Anyway, that does not resolve the problem :-(

Comment: Problem resolved, the final issue solution is to not split token, the response of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800675/error-migrating-existing-oauth-credentials-to-acaccountstore) is wrong.